# Package structure for functions with multiple possible outcomes

Tags: r, function, architecture, r-package

I am maintaining and upgrading a not so small internal package in R and would appreciate some tips and opinions on best practices to maintain functions with many possible scenarios.

An example:

Suppose I have a function that does some computations on an object, but these computations can be done using several techniques, which I'll call "type" for simplicity, with each technique having multiple settings parameters to it. (They each have default values, I jsut used some numbers for simplification.)

For instance:

```
foo <- function(x, type = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                param1_a = 1, param2_a = 2, param1_b = 3, param1_c = 4, param2_c = 5){
   type <- match.arg(type)
   ### some common computations here

   if(type == "a"){
      ### computations using type "a"
   }
   else if(type == "b"){
      ### computations using type "b"
   }
   else if(type == "c"){
      ### computations using type "c"
   }
}
```

Now this seems not good, so what I did was to change some things, such as creating individual functions for each type and setting the parameters in each function definition, instead of on the main function:

```
foo <- function(x, type = c("a", "b", "c"), ...){
   type <- match.arg(type)
   ### some common computations here

   if(type == "a"){
      foo_a(x, ...)
   }
   else if(type == "b"){
      foo_b(x, ...)
   }
   else if(type == "c"){
      foo_c(x, ...)
   }
}

foo_a <- function(x, param1_a = 1, param2_a = 2){
   ### computations using type "a"
}

foo_a <- function(x, param1_b = 3){
   ### computations using type "b"
}

foo_c <- function(x, param1_c = 4, param2_c = 5){
   ### computations using type "c"
}
```

What I am interested in learning is:
Is this usually considered best practices in maintaining these type of functions in a package?
If not, then I'd gladly take any tips, suggestions or reading material on the best (or better) ways to oganize it.

Comment: I would still prefer the first form, because it allows you to document all the parameters. Just make clear in the documentation, for which method each parameter is.

Comment: A more idiomatic R way to do this would probably be using S3 dispatching. See more at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: @Stibu thanks for the comment, but I think (correct me if I'm wrong) I can still use Roxygen2 comments to document the parameters even if they are explicitly defined on the main function

Comment: @MrFlick In this case would you consider creating classes for each option in "type" and then implementing methods for `foo` like `foo.a`, `foo.b` and `foo.c`?

Comment: Yes. Then each of those functions can be documented with their different parameters but you don't necessarily have to export them from your package as separate functions if you don't want to. For example the `print()` method is generic and you can see all it's custom versions with `methods("print")`